# Vercel Edge Functions works locally and give 404 on production when trying to work with 'hostname-rewrites'

Tags: next.js, url-rewriting, serverless, vercel

I'm trying to work with the new edge functions from Vercel next.js and it's not working on production, always gives a 404 error.

I followed this [example](https://github.com/vercel/examples/tree/main/edge-functions/hostname-rewrites) and nothing works.

maybe because I'm using i18n?

my `_middleware.js` file looks like this:

```
import {NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export default function middleware(req) {
    const { pathname } = req.nextUrl
    let hostname = req.headers.get('host')


if (
    !pathname.includes('.') && // exclude all files in the public folder
    !pathname.startsWith('/api') // exclude all API routes
) {
    if (
        !hostname.includes('example.vercel.app') &&
        hostname !== 'example.com' &&
        hostname !== 'localhost:3000'
    ) {
        return NextResponse.rewrite(`/_sites/${hostname}${pathname}`)
    }
}
}
```

And under pages I'm using this structure:

```
/pages
 /_sites
  [sites]
    index.js
```

Please help me find a solution for that.

Comment: Is that your _full_ folder structure? Where is the `_middleware.js` file? It needs to be under the `pages` folder to run.

Comment: were you found the workaround for this ?